# Nginx Laravel subloder installation syays 403 forbidden but adding /public/index.php loads page

Tags: laravel, nginx

My Nginx Laravel subloder installation syays 403 forbidden but adding /public/index.php in the browser URL loads page.

> Permissions are set correctly as far as I know-

```
sudo chown -R madguy:www-data /var/www/madguy.com/horizontal-laravel

sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www/madguy.com/horizontal-laravel

sudo chgrp -R www-data storage bootstrap/cache

sudo chmod -R ug+rwx storage bootstrap/cache
```

Here is my config-

```
# Webroot Directory for Laravel project
     root /var/www/madguy;
     index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

     # Your Domain Name
     server_name madguy.com www.madguy.com;

     location / {
             try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
     }

     # PHP-FPM Configuration Nginx
    location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    }

    location /horizontal-laravel {
           try_files $uri $uri/ /horizontal-laravel/public;
    }
```

What is wrong in the config please?

EDIT: Also all the routes goes back to the same dashboard page.

Comment: What is the URI you are trying? What access and error log entries are there? What do you expect to happen?

Comment: @RichardSmith The URI i am trying is madguy.com but rerurns 404. But when I try madguy.com/public, then it works. I( would like it to work on the root and get rid of the /public part. And when I click on the other page link, it redirects back to the root dashboard page for some reason.

Comment: If `index.php` is at `/var/www/madguy/public/index.php`, then either your `root` needs to be `/var/www/madguy/public`, or your `try_files` needs to end with `/public/index.php`.

Comment: @RichardSmith If I have two folders, is there a way to have the root serve one and then a location block serve another? And I tried with /public/index.php inside the location block, same result. This  /public/index.php part is not being picked up by the location block for some reason and there is not error logged too.

Comment: You need to explain your file structure clearly and the URIs you want to use to access it. It is not clear where `horizontal-laravel` fits in. Relevant access log entries will show which URIs you are testing together with their response code.